# Android immediately run on ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, android-handler, ui-thread

I have read a lot of other answers on StackOverflow, cant seem to find my answer.

I have a listener in my class, i perform a long running task in an async block:

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
   // long running task here
   // ...
   listener.updateTitle(newTitle);
});
```

Once I have the data I pass it back to the relevant class:

```
 @Override
 public void updateTitle(String newTitle) {
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> title.setText(newTitle));
 }
```

Now from what I researched online calling `runOnUiThread(..)` adds the runnable to a queue of tasks that need to be run on ui. My problem is this updating the title is more important than any of the other ui tasks running.

Is it possible to add this task to the front of the queue, or execute currently executing task, then execute this new task and continue executing the tasks as they were in the previous order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtFrontOfQueue(() -> title.setText(newTitle));
```

It may not be sufficient for your needs though as this action will be executed with some delay anyway. If you need to update the title for the next frame, you may want to consider subclassing TextView and providing a synchronized method for setting text from any thread.

Comment: Would you be able to give a high level overview of how you would achieve something like this? Wont you always need to request the UI thread to modify views anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. If your UI thread is busy that you need to wait for the title to be updated, you need to re-think you app design not find a way to get ahead of the Q.
2. From the AsynTask, to get something to be run in UI thread, use [publishProgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

HTH